# Solution of advection-diffusion PDE breaks down once axial diffusion is added

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method

I am considering the following advection-diffusion problem, characterised by three positive real parameters `Pe`, `α` and `ω`:

```
sol[Pe_, α_, ω_] := 
  NDSolve
    [{D[r D[c[r, z], r], r] - 2  r Pe /α (1 - r^2) D[c[r, z], z] == 0,
      c[r, 0] == -1, (* inlet condition *)
      0 == D[c[r, z], r] /. r -> 0, (* no flux at cylinder axis *)
      c[1, z] == -ω D[c[r, z], r] /. r -> 1 (* 'uptake' *)}, 
     c, {r, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
     SolveDelayed -> True, 
     AccuracyGoal -> 15][[1]]
```

[image: Plot of solution without axial diffusion.]

Now I add an axial diffusion term to the PDE, which I match with an outlet condition, i.e. a condition at the z=1 boundary:

```
sol[Pe_, α_, ω_] := 
  NDSolve[
   {r D[c[r, z], {z, 2}] + D[r D[c[r, z], r], r] - 
      2  r Pe /α (1 - r^2) D[c[r, z], z] == 0,
    c[r, 0] == -1, (* inlet condition *)
    0 == D[c[r, z], r] /. r -> 0, (* no flux at cylinder 
    c[1, z] == -ω D[c[r, z], r] /. r -> 1 (* 'uptake' *),
    c[r, 1] == 0 (* outlet condition *)},
    c, {r, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
    SolveDelayed -> True, 
    AccuracyGoal -> 15][[1]]
```

The output is:

[image]

The output is very similar for an outlet condition of 0 == D[c[r, z], z] /. z -> 1.

I am not sure what is going on here. I believe the last problem is well-posed since I have an outlet condition. Please let me know what your thoughts are, and how to interpret Mathematica's error messages here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, figured it out! Mathematica misunderstood my Robin BC as a Dirichlet BC, which is why it gave the above error message. Instead of writing things like c[1, z] == -ω D[c[r, z], r] /. r -> 1 (which Mathematica misinterprets), properly specifying boundary conditions with NeumannValue and DirichletCondition gets the job done.

```
\[CapitalOmega] := Rectangle[{0, 0}, {Xmax, 1}];
(* RegionPlot[\[CapitalOmega]/.Xmax\[Rule]10, \
AspectRatio\[Rule]Automatic] *)
op := 
 Pe  Y (1 - Y/2) D[c[X, Y], X] - D[c[X, Y], {Y, 2}]
op := Pe  Y (1 - Y/2) \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(X\)]\(c[X, Y]\)\) - \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({X, Y}\), \(2\)]\(c[X, Y]\)\) 
\[CapitalGamma]N := NeumannValue[-\[Mu]eff c[X, Y], Y == 0]
\[CapitalGamma]N2 := NeumannValue[0, X == Xmax]
\[CapitalGamma]D1 := DirichletCondition[c[X, Y] == 1, X == 0]
\[CapitalGamma]D2 := DirichletCondition[c[X, Y] == 0, X == Xmax]

Pe = 10;
\[Mu]eff = 10;
Xmax = 11;
sol = NDSolveValue[{op == \[CapitalGamma]N + \[CapitalGamma]N2, \
\[CapitalGamma]D1 , \[CapitalGamma]D2}, 
  c, {X, Y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]]
ContourPlot[sol[X, Y], {X, 0, Xmax}, {Y, 0, 1}, 
 Contours -> Table[ci, {ci, 0, 1, 1/20 // N}], AxesLabel -> {X, Y}, 
 AspectRatio -> 0.2, ContourLabels -> True, AxesLabel -> {X, Y},  
 PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 0.3, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  "Pe = " <> ToString[Pe] <> 
   ",  \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Mu]\), \(eff\)]\) = " <> 
   ToString[\[Mu]eff]]
(*Plot3D[sol[X,Y],{X,0,Xmax},{Y,0,1},AxesLabel\[Rule]{X,Y,c},  \
PlotRange\[Rule]All]*)
```

I focused on the following similar (but mildly easier) boundary value problem from [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10665-008-9239-x):
[image]

My numerics produced with the above code (left) appears to be a very good match to the published result (right).
[image]